Move array elements in a circle
Please, tell me, how you can move the elements of an array in a circle. For example, there is an array:
{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20}

What command can I use to get the following result:
{5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 1, 2, 3, 4}

I really hope for you.

list = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18,     19, 20}; RotateLeft[list, 4]

list = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20};

RotateLeft (as commented by cvgmt) is the way to go, but there are many more possibilities, for example
TakeList
Flatten @ TakeList[list, {-16, ;;}]

Part
Flatten @ {list[[5 ;;]], list[[;; 4]]}

Take
Flatten @ {Take[list, -16], Take[list, 4]}

All produce

{5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 1, 2, 3, 4}

